# How to hide <templatefield></templatefield> and display it dynamically using code?

Tags: html, vb.net

It's the nested `GridView` scenario.

I want to hide `<templatefield>` which contains one `<div>` and also space should not be left when child gridview is not displayed...

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlgvwSubjectStatus" runat="server" Style="max-height: 500px; overflow: auto; width: 60%;">
             <asp:GridView ID="gvwSubjectForProject" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SkinID="grdViewSmlAutoSize" Width="70%" ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="1">
                 <Columns>
                     <asp:TemplateField>
                         <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnExpand" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/Plus.gif" alt="Expand" OnClientClick="imgbtnExpand_Click" />
                             <asp:HiddenField ID="hcStatus" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("cStatus") %>' />
                         </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="STATUS">
                         <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="40%" />
                         <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="40%" />
                     </asp:BoundField>
                     <asp:TemplateField>
                         <ItemTemplate>
                             <div id="div_gvChild" runat="server" style="max-height: 300px; width: 100%; overflow: auto; text-align: right;">
                                 <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Width="100%">
                                     <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SkinID="grdViewSmlAutoSize">
                                         <Columns>
                                             <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="40%" DataField="vSubjectID" HeaderText="SUBJECT ID">
                                                 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="40%" />
                                                 <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="40%" />
                                             </asp:BoundField>
                                             <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="60%" DataField="FullName" HeaderText="FULL NAME">
                                                 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="60%" />
                                                 <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="60%" />
                                             </asp:BoundField>
                                         </Columns>
                                     </asp:GridView>
                                </asp:Panel>
                             </div>
                         </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalSubject" HeaderText="TOTAL SUBJECTS">
                         <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="50%" />
                         <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" Width="50%" />
                     </asp:BoundField>
                 </Columns>
             </asp:GridView>
         </asp:Panel>
```

I don't want to display any left blank space for child `GridView` when it is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Give it an id or class and target it with jquery:

```
$('.div_gvChild-css-class').Show();
//or
$('#div_gvChild').Show();

$('.div_gvChild-css-class').Hide();
//or
$('#div_gvChild').Hide();
```

To remove the white space add "display:none" to your style tag:

```
<div id="div_gvChild" runat="server" style="display:none; max-height: 300px; width: 100%; overflow: auto; text-align: right">
```

If you want it to look fancier, you can use the SlideUp()/SlideDown() functions

Comment: This is for client side, I'm assuming you want to do this dynamically on the client side?

Comment: No its not working because hiding {<DIV>} is still filling a blank space in parent gridview.

Comment: Give the div an initial style of "display:none" that should take away the white space

Comment: style="max-height: 300px; width: 100%; overflow: auto;text-align: right; **display:none**"

Comment: Could you perhaps create a jsfiddle to illustrate your issue?